# Multiple values in MySQL variable

Tags: mysql

The following works as expected when there is a single value stored in a variable.

```
SET @a := "20100630";
SELECT * FROM wordbase WHERE verified = @a;
```

But it does not work when there are multiple values stored in a variable.

```
SET @a := "'20100630', '20100701' ";
SELECT * FROM wordbase WHERE verified in (@a);
```

Do I need to use prepared statements for this?

Comment: SET @a := "'20100630', '20100701' " should be SET @a := "20100630, 20100701". You'd added quotes for integer values, which caused it to return no rows

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot (as far as I am aware) store multiple values in a MySQL user defined variable.  What you have done is create a string which contains:

```
'20100630', '20100701'
```

That is not two separate values, but a single string value, just as this is a single string value:

```
SET @a := "It's a single string, and that's the problem";
```

You need to use two separate variables, or prepare a statement, like this:

```
SET @a := "20100630";
SET @b := "20100701";

SET @sql = CONCAT(
    'SELECT * FROM wordbase WHERE verified IN (',
    @a,
    ',',
    @b,
    ')'
);


SELECT @sql;
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| @sql                                                         |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| SELECT * FROM wordbase WHERE verified IN (20100630,20100701) |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

But that's kinda messy.  Why do you need to use variables?

Answer (score 33):

There's good solution described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11957706/1523961

So you can use something like this:

```sql
SET @a := '20100630,20100701';
SELECT * FROM wordbase WHERE FIND_IN_SET(verified, @a);
```

Also, if you're selecting the ids for `@a` from another table, you can come up with the following:

```sql
SET @a := (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) FROM someTable where yourBooleanExpressionHere);
SELECT * FROM wordbase WHERE FIND_IN_SET(verified, @a);
```

Answer (score 6):

Using `GROUP_CONCAT` and `GROUP BY` one could pull all values ( i.e. an id ) into a variable like so:

```
SET @var := (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) FROM `table` WHERE `verified` = @verified GROUP BY verified);
```

Comment: depends on the amount of values. GROUP_CONCAT has a maximum length.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work. Is it ok to use prepared statements to create temporary tables like this?

```
SET @a := "'20100630', '20100701'";
SET @sql = CONCAT('create temporary table pn1 SELECT * FROM wordbase WHERE verified IN (', @a, ')');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;

select * from pn1;
```

Comment: I know this is an old post but this worked perfectly especially when you have multiple values.

Answer (score 1):

FIND_IN_SET(column to find in , string csv) is a very handy method in case you have the string list of CSV:

```
SET @a := "'20100630', '20100701' ";
SELECT * FROM wordbase WHERE FIND_IN_SET(verified, @a);
```

if your variable is also coming from query then use this to set @a

```
SET @a := (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`id`) FROM `table`);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use your variable for a select or delete you can use select in the select:

```
delete from  MPCurrentPayEntitlementAccrual where CurrentPayEntitlementID in (  select CurrentPayEntitlementID from MPCurrentPayEntitlement where PayRunID=myPayRunId by PayRunID desc);
```

That worked perfectly for me

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(field_table1 SEPARATOR ',') FROM table1 into @var;
```

then

```
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE field_table2 in(@var);
```

works fine for me

Comment: I fail to see how this can work. First query creates a massive string which is the concatenation of `field_table1` after converting it to a string. Second query checks whether `field_table2` is equal to that massive string.

Comment: This might look like it worked if you only ever retrieve *one* value from table1. Then @var will be equal to that one value, and the second select will, indeed, search and find the rows where field_table2 has that value.

But if the values are two, say "A" and "B", the search will be for "A,B"; so, table2 rows with "A" will not be selected, because "A" is not "A,B", and neither will rows with "B". The query will return without errors, but without data.

Comment: Hey, `GROUP_CONCAT(field_table1 SEPARATOR ',')` builds a string like: `1,,2,,3`, I think that `GROUP_CONCAT(field_table1)` is enough