# MySQL variable format for a "NOT IN" list of values

Tags: mysql, sql, in-clause

Going crazy trying to set a variable in a query of type:

```
SET @idcamposexcluidos='817,803,495';
```

so i can then use it on a

```
WHERE id_campo not in (@idcamposexcluidos)
```

I've tried defining the variable in different formats with no luck and don't seem to find an specific example for the above:

```
SET @idcamposexcluidos='(817,803,495)';
...
WHERE id_campo not in @idcamposexcluidos


SET @idcamposexcluidos=817,803,495;
```

with no success. It either returns an error or ignores the values.

Comment: You can't use `in` like that. You need seperate variables or use a dynamic SQL.

Comment: `FIND_IN_SET` and `LIKE` are OK for small tables.  But they do not perform well because they have to look at every row.  Most languages have no simple way (if any way) to construct the much faster `IN(...)` clause, which can use an index.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

You can't use the `IN` clause like that. It compiles to a **single** string in your `IN` clause. But an `IN` clause needs **separate** values.

```
WHERE id_campo not in (@idcamposexcluidos)
```

compiles to

```
WHERE id_campo not in ('817,803,495')
```

but it should be

```
WHERE id_campo not in ('817','803','495')
```

To overcome this either use dynamic SQL or in MySQL you could use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SET @idcamposexcluidos='817,803,495';
...
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id_campo, @idcamposexcluidos) = 0
```

but using a function like `FIND_IN_SET()` can not make use of indexes.

Comment: Awesome! At first I thought this wasn't going to work because I both overlooked and was not familiar with the FIND_IN_SET method. I was afraid that '80' would produce a false positive because of '803' but it works wonderfully!

Comment: And if you like to use a IN clause instead of NOT IN, just replace '= 0' with '> 0' --> WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id_campo, @idcamposexcluidos) > 0

Comment: @Bruno you could also do: `WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id_campo, @idcamposexcluidos)`. Which is to say, treat the result of `FIND_IN_SET` like a boolean. The answer for NOT IN equivalent expression could also be written like this: `WHERE NOT FIND_IN_SET(id_campo, @idcamposexcluidos)`

Comment: Important note about this: the database engine doesn't seem to be smart enough to optimize queries. `EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT * FROM users WHERE FIND_IN_SET(user_id, @userlist)`  ==> Full table scan (very slow on large table). `EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)` ==> Uses primary key index (very fast). (Tested on MySQL 5.6/innodb.)

Comment: @Kip: Using functions generally prevent using indexes.

Comment: I don't think `NOT IN (....)` will use an index anyway.  So `FIND_IN_SET` may be the "best" answer.

Comment: @RickJames: My understanding is that is depends. But the optimizers tries to use an index.

Answer (score 4):

By using `CONCAT()`, a pipe-separator (instead of a comma), and a little "reverse logic", you can use a variable in your `NOT IN` list, but instead - by using `NOT LIKE`!

Example:

```
SET @idcamposexcluidos = '|817|803|495|';

SELECT
    *
FROM
    your_table
WHERE
    @idcamposexcluidos NOT LIKE CONCAT('%|', id_campo, '|%');
```

This should work with both string and numeric columns alike.

Comment: seems to work as well but not sure why I get more rows on the same search ! Any case juergen d solution works great. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

if you use mysql > 5.1, you can use:

```
CREATE TYPE lista as (
    clave int4,
    valor int4
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(IN vArray lista[])
...

   WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id_campo, vArray)
...
```

in other case you can use a trick:

```
WHERE id_campo IN ( SELECT 817 as valor UNION ALL 
                SELECT 803 as valor UNION ALL
                    SELECT 495 as valor)
```