# How to pass a list of IDs to MySQL stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm writing a stored procedure which should pass its arguments to `IN (..)` part of query in the procedure body, like this:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `get_users_per_app` (id_list TEXT)
BEGIN
    SELECT app_id, GROUP_CONCAT(user_id) FROM app_users WHERE app_id IN (id_list) GROUP BY app_id;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

This, obviously, doesn't work because when I pass a textual value, `id_list` is interpolated as an integer and only first ID is considered and used inside of `IN()` condition.

I realize that this particular type of procedure could be instead replaced by the contained query, but I think that my question still stands - what if I needed to pass this kind of data?

*I also realize that this approach of query might not be considered the best practice, but in my use case it's actually better than returning a flat list of ID-ID pairs..*

Comment: Check out the answer(s) to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957643/mysql-variable-format-for-a-not-in-list-of-values

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You should be able to use MySQL's [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) to use the list of ids:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `get_users_per_app` (id_list TEXT)
BEGIN
    SELECT
        app_id, GROUP_CONCAT(user_id)
    FROM
        app_users
    WHERE
        FIND_IN_SET(app_id, id_list) > 0
    GROUP BY app_id;
    ...
```

Comment: I totally forgot about FIND_IN_SET(), thanks for that comment above, too.

Comment: Be mindful of spaces that you may have in your list.  I.e. for a zip code example, '30305,30308' does not perform the same as '30305, 30308'

Answer (score 0):

i was able to find a solution to this question, if you want to use ***NOT IN*** function in MySQL then you can try to use the following code. i hope this will be useful. it works like ***NOT IN*** except you pass the ***comma separated*** string

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `get_users_per_app` (id_list TEXT)
BEGIN
    SELECT
        app_id, GROUP_CONCAT(user_id)
    FROM
        app_users
    WHERE
       app_id NOT FIND_IN_SET(app_id, id_list)
    GROUP BY app_id;
```