# MYSQL variable IN clause

Tags: mysql

In filtering out some spam, I have two MYSQL statements in one file,

```
SET @valid_users := '"admin", "jrock", "kmicka", "First Last"';  //etc
```

Followed by a SELECT like this

```
SELECT /*stuff*/ /*WHERE*/ /*filters*/ AND User.user_name NOT IN (@valid_users)
```

When I do this, it acts as if `@valid_users` is an empty string. (Returns all results).  But if I change the clause to `NOT IN ('admin', 'jrock', etc)` then it works as it should.

Why would a variable in the `NOT IN` filter not work?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957643/mysql-variable-format-for-a-not-in-list-of-values).

Comment: Thanks, didn't see that questions when searching.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You'll want to take a look at MySQL's [`find_in_set()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    your_table
WHERE
    NOT FIND_IN_SET(User.user_name, @valid_users);
```

For this to work, the comma-separated list shouldn't contain quotes (unless your usernames actually contain quotes) and should not be padded with spaces:

```
SET @valid_users := 'admin,jrock,kmicka,First Last';
```

[**SqlFiddle Example**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6c36/3/1)

To directly answer your question regarding "why would a variable in the `NOT IN` filter work", it's because `@valid_users` is being treated as a string and when you pass it to `IN()`, it's being treated as a single string (i.e. not a set/list). With `FIND_IN_SET()`, it treats the string in `@valid_users` as a comma-separated set/list and uses it accordingly.

Comment: Technically, `!FIND_IN_SET()`, but it still didn't work. Same results as before. It could be the quotes affecting things here-- there is no user named \"admin\". I got it to work by copy/paste my list to remove the variable, but it's just not as clean as with the variable, and it still doesn't explain _why_ my original code did not work.

Thanks

Comment: @theHampster Please see my updated answer that should hopefully clarify your issue =]

Comment: Thanks. I'm chalking this up to poor language constructions. IN cannot use strings, but accepts things that "look" like strings.