# MySql: return a list of Ids in a variable and reuse that variable in an IN CLAUSE

Tags: mysql

Please see sample code

```
-- 1st select, getting AssetID from asset table
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(AssetID)
INTO @AssetIDs
FROM  asset;

-- 2nd select, use @AssetIDs in an IN clause 
SELECT AssetID
from asset
where AssetID IN (@AssetIDs)
```

From the 1st select, it returns 10 IDs and those IDs get stored in `@AssetIDs`
So i would imagine `@AssetIDs = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10'`

However, the second `select` always return the first ID, 1.

Can anyone help me find a way to select the list of IDs in a variable that reuse that variable in the IN clause?

Comment: Why use a variable at all? just `in (select AssetID from asset)` - If you reall have to do it see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21101211/mysql-variable-in-clause

Comment: @AlexK. and then it all just comes down to `select AssetID from asset` as the simplest query anyway with no `IN`

Comment: @drew ha yes good point

Comment: In order to evaluate `where AssetID IN ('1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10')`, MySQL implicitely converts your string '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10' to int which it does by simply taking all digits from left, which is '1' only. So the query finds the record with ID 1. I don't like this conversion very much, I'd rather see it resulting in an error, because '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10' obviously isn't an integer. But well, this is how the MySQL guys decided to do it.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner ahh i see it now. That's why it's always returning the first ID

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used a tmp table instead.

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmpassetlist; 
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpassetlist AS
(
    SELECT AssetID
    FROM asset
    WHERE (condition)
);
```

Then do a join:

```
SELECT AssetID
from asset JOIN tmpassetlist
ON asset.AssetID = tmpassetlist.AssetID
```

I think it's also better performance wise because `IN` clause could get very slow when the list gets longer.