# GROUP CONCAT not working in a subquery - mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, opencart, group-concat

I have a mysql query which I've written in order to grab a group of attributes in the database based on IDs, which relate to a specific group. I'm using OpenCart 2 for my site, and my subquery is as follows:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(attribute_id) AS attr_ids 
FROM oc79_attribute 
WHERE attribute_group_id = 13
```

Which returns:

> 44,45,46,47

When I write this within the query which I need to get the attribute names, I only get one result:

```
SELECT * 
FROM oc79_attribute_description 
WHERE attribute_id IN(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(attribute_id) AS attr_ids 
                      FROM oc79_attribute WHERE attribute_group_id = 13)
```

I only get the result from attribute_id 44, and not the others even though I know the records exist.

Is this the right way to approach this, or am I just missing something?

EDIT:

To clarify, if I write:

```
SELECT * FROM oc79_attribute_description WHERE attribute_id IN(44,45,46,47)
```

I get the correct result of 4 records.

Thanks in advance

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11957706/575376

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM oc79_attribute_description 
WHERE attribute_id IN(SELECT attribute_id AS attr_ids 
                      FROM oc79_attribute
                      WHERE attribute_group_id = 13);
```

See the difference between:

```
WHERE attribute_id IN ('44,45,46,47')     -- one string
```

and

```
WHERE attribute_id IN ('44','45','46','47')  -- multiple values
```

`GROUP_CONCAT` will return one string with `,` as separator, what you need is multiple values.

Answer (score 1):

If the attribute table only has one row per attribute_id then you can use a join simple:-

```
SELECT oc79_attribute_description.* 
FROM oc79_attribute_description 
INNER JOIN oc79_attribute 
ON oc79_attribute_description.attribute_id = oc79_attribute.attribute_id 
AND oc79_attribute.attribute_group_id = 13
```

If it has multiples then you could use DISTINCT:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT oc79_attribute_description.* 
FROM oc79_attribute_description 
INNER JOIN oc79_attribute 
ON oc79_attribute_description.attribute_id = oc79_attribute.attribute_id 
AND oc79_attribute.attribute_group_id = 13
```

If you really wanted to search through a string of comma separated values (and I really would advise against it) then you could use FIND_IN_SET:-

```
SELECT * 
FROM oc79_attribute_description 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(attribute_id, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(attribute_id) AS attr_ids 
                      FROM oc79_attribute WHERE attribute_group_id = 13))
```