# select a row using a value in comma separated fields

Tags: mysql

I have to select a row from a table 'seller' which have two columns 'cat' and 'place' in which multiple ids are stored with commas

```
'seller' table
╔═══╦════════╦══════════════╗
║ id║cat     ║    place     ║
╠═══╬════════╬══════════════╣ 
║ 8 ║1,2     ║ 1,2,3,4      ║
╚═══╩════════╩══════════════╝
```

my mysql query

```
SELECT * FROM `seller` WHERE cat like '%1%' && place LIKE '%2%'
```

but i know it is bad query.if there is 12 it will treated as both 1 and 2.
is there any good query??.

Comment: Can you change the table design?

Comment: use `in`  like  `cat in(1,2,3)`.

Comment: @Suchit: That will not work

Comment: @juergend sorry i just saw the question and replied.

Comment: i have to store multiple ids in fields thats why i used comma separation

Comment: @Suchit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957643/mysql-variable-format-for-a-not-in-list-of-values/11957706#11957706

Comment: @juergend got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
SELECT * FROM `seller` 
WHERE find_in_set(1, cat) > 0
and find_in_set(2, place) > 0
```

But you should actually change your table design.

#### Never store multiple values in a single column!

That is a classic *n to m relation*. A better design would be

```
seller table
------------
id
name
...


categories table
----------------
id
name


seller_categories table
-----------------------
seller_id
category_id
```

Comment: Thanks.your query working fine.I am using a multiselect dropdown to store in both columns thats why i used comma.

Comment: There is no excuse for using a comma separated list in a column. None!