# How to search a string within a dynamic list of string in MYSQL Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mariadb

In my database I'm searching for a list of ID's like this:

```sql
SELECT * from testcase where id in ('658', '659');
```

But how can I make this into a stored procedure, which can take multiple id's?

In this example I have only `'658', '659'` but this could be more/less.

I made a stored procedure, but either it failes because I have two id's or more, and if I make it into a single string like this, `'658, 659'`, then it only find the results from `658`:

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`edmetrics`@`%` PROCEDURE `GetCaseFromStrList`(CaseIDs varchar(300))
BEGIN
IF CaseIDs != 0 OR CaseIDs IS NOT NULL THEN
        Select testcase.id, testcase.TestCaseName
      From testcase
      Where testcase.id in (CaseIDs);
    END IF;
END
```

Is there a way to make a call like this, with multiple X amount of id's?

```sql
CALL database.GetCaseFromStrList(658 , 659);
```

**EDIT - more info**

Was told I cold look at this solution, but it's not 100% the thing im looking for: [StackOverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957643/mysql-variable-format-for-a-not-in-list-of-values)

But I will show an example with pictures

When I write this SQL: `SELECT * from testcase where id in ('658', '659');` I get the following result

[Table result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vISf6.png)

If I try to implement the linked solution with `FIND_IN_SET()` in my stored procedure I have this:

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`edmetrics`@`%` PROCEDURE `GetCaseFromStrList`(CaseIDs varchar(300))
BEGIN
SET @idCaseIDs = CaseIDs;
IF CaseIDs != 0 OR CaseIDs IS NOT NULL THEN
        Select testcase.id, testcase.TestCaseName
      From testcase
      WHERE FIND_IN_SET(testcase.id, @idCaseIDs);
    END IF;
END
```

But if I use a string with all the ID's in it, and make a call like this:
`CALL testreporting.GetCaseFromStrList('658, 659');`

I get the following result

[Table result from stored procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2D1h.png)

And in that result I'm missing the ID `659`.

and remember this is with two ID's, but I can have X amount of ID's not only two.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL variable format for a "NOT IN" list of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957643/mysql-variable-format-for-a-not-in-list-of-values)

Comment: @AndrewMorton Not really, I will post pictures to make a better understanding of my problem

Comment: try:  **WHERE FIND_IN_SET(testcase.id, CaseIDs )** or see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149545/pass-array-to-mysql-stored-routine

Comment: @BerndBuffen read the edit..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fIND_IN_SET works just fine, see example

> ```
> CREATE TABLE testcase(id int,TestCaseName varchar(50) )
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO testcase VALUES (658,'test1'),(659,'test2')
> ```

> ```
> CREATE  PROCEDURE `GetCaseFromStrList`(_CaseIDs varchar(300))
> BEGIN
>
> IF _CaseIDs != 0 OR _CaseIDs IS NOT NULL THEN
>         Select testcase.id, testcase.TestCaseName
>       From testcase
>       WHERE FIND_IN_SET(testcase.id, _CaseIDs);
>     END IF;
> END
> ```

> ```
> CALL GetCaseFromStrList('658,659')
> ```
>
> ```
>  id | TestCaseName
> --: | :-----------
> 658 | test1       
> 659 | test2       
>
> ✓
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=8a3c668f7591cb3b8110bd20a442c63d)*

Answer (score 0):

`Find_IN_SET` is returning the position of the first string in the array of strings. So when you are string value is 658 it's returning 1 so `WHERE FIND_IN_SET(testcase.id, @idCaseIDs)` is true since in MySQL 1 represents that. But when the string value is 659 it's returning 2 which is not equivalent of `true`.

Instead please use condition `FIND_IN_SET(testcase.id, @idCaseIDs)>0` to get your desired results.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`edmetrics`@`%` PROCEDURE `GetCaseFromStrList`(CaseIDs varchar(300))
BEGIN
SET @idCaseIDs = CaseIDs;
IF CaseIDs != 0 OR CaseIDs IS NOT NULL THEN
        Select testcase.id, testcase.TestCaseName
      From testcase
      WHERE FIND_IN_SET(testcase.id, @idCaseIDs)>0;
    END IF;
END
```