# How to resolve the error 1292 on using a comma separated string inside IN() in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am using the query

```
select * from wallet_transaction where id IN('12,13');
```

I got '12,13' from GROUP_CONCAT()

it gives this error

```
Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '12,13'
```

One solution i got is switching off the strict mode but i don't want to do this

what's the solution ?

Comment: data type of ```id``` is ```int```. I got ```'12,13'``` from ```GROUP_CONCAT()``` which automatically creates a string having commas but as this is a string it gives error inside ```IN()```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11957706/575376

Comment: Either FIND_IN_SET or dynamic SQL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL variable format for a "NOT IN" list of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957643/mysql-variable-format-for-a-not-in-list-of-values)

Answer (score 0):

When we use GROUP_CONCAT(), this will automatically become a string that's why you are facing the issue. IN value is considering the Integer. Please write as below query.

```
select * from wallet_transaction where id IN(12,13);
```